# Id encoding differences across platforms?

Tags: javascript

When I run, for example,

```
uts47.encode("⚽️")


xn--y8hw789ec0vgbfb
```

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Please do not replace your question by spam-text. If you do not want it anymore you can **delete** it. But I am not sure why you would want this, it is a good question with up-votes and a good answer. If the answer solved your question, you might want to mark it as **accepted**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [idna-uts46](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idna-uts46) package to get Chrome-like result:

```
var uts46 = require('idna-uts46');
uts46.toAscii("⚽️"); // produces "xn--y8h2559nb4a"
```